# Cannot open newly downloaded blender on my new chrome laptop

Tags: animation, linux

I just tried to download the 64 bit linux version on my new chromebook.   It allows me to download it, but says I cannot open it as it does not support his version.  Note that my chromebook has linux beta already on the laptop.  Is there an app that I need to download for it to recognize the files?

Comment: You need to have an actual desktop os like windows or ubuntu. you can download and get rid of chrome os. There are many tutorials on how to do this on youtube.